# Showing that $\mathscr{O} = \mathscr{O}+c$ where $\mathscr{O}$ is the collection of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-explanation

$\newcommand{\scrO}{\mathscr{O}}$
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\preim}{\text{preim}}$
**Proposition:** Let $\scrO$ be the collection of all open sets in $\R$ and for any $c \in \R$ define
$$
\scrO+c = \{A +c \mid A \in \scrO \} \text{ and } A+c = \{x+c \mid x \in A\}.
$$
Show that $\scrO+c = \scrO$.

The proof simply writes that $f:\R \rightarrow \R$ by $x \mapsto x+c$ is a homeomorphism, but I am not very familiar with the terminology. From some cursory reading a map $f:X \rightarrow Y$ between two topological spaces is a homeomorphism if it is a continuous map possessing a continuous inverse $f^{-1}:Y \rightarrow X$. That's fair enough to see here, $f(x) = x+c$ and $f^{-1}(x) = x-c$ certainly work as
$$
(f\circ f^{-1})(x) = f(x-c) = x \text{ and } (f^{-1} \circ f)(x) = f^{-1}(x+c) = x,
$$
and both are continuous. So fair enough $f$ is a homeomorphism, but from this what are you supposed to conclude?

*Attempt:* I think that if $O \in \scrO$ then $\preim_{f^{-1}}(O) = O+c$ is open since the continuous preimage of an open set is open by definition, and therefore we conclude that $O+c \in \scrO$ and so $\scrO+c \subseteq \scrO$? So I just need to find the reverse inclusion? Thanks in advance for the clarification.

Comment: Just replace $f$ with $f^{-1}$, i.e. $c$ with $-c$. Since $f$ is bijective, the preimage of $f$ ($f^{-1}$) is the same as the forward image of $f^{-1}$ ($f$).

Comment: Oh yeah just set $f(x) =x-c$ from the start cuts out the middle man, thanks @TheoBendit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is an homeomorphism then, by definition of homeomorphism, $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ is open if and only if $A+c$ is also open, therefore both $A$ and $A+c$ belong to $\mathscr{O}$ for any chosen open $A$, so $\mathscr{O}=\mathscr{O}+c$.∎